# Is this a valid abstract class?

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class, default, abstract

Is this a valid abstract class?

I know that abstract classes cannot be instantiated, so I'm suspicious of the instance variable `language` and constructor `Programmer`. It also implements a `writeCode` method that is not declared as `default`. If I recall correctly, the only methods that can be implemented in an abstract class are those with default implementations.

```
public abstract class Programmer {
     private String language;
     public Programmer (String language) {
          this.language = language;
     }
     public void writeCode() {
          System.out.println("Written in " + language);
     }
}
```

- If it is a valid abstract class, can someone explain why it contains a constructor?
- Also, more broadly speaking, can abstract classes have instance variables? If so, why? Doesn't that seem counter to the idea that abstract classes cannot be instantiated?
- Finally, I would love it if someone addresses the `writeCode` method. Why is it implemented, without a `default` modifier?

Thanks!

Comment: YES! The subclases will need to invoke to `super(languaje);` at first time in theirs constructors.

Comment: You seem to be confusing between `interfaces` and `abstract classes`

Comment: **Any** class can be declared `abstract` (it may not makes sense but absolutely legal).

Comment: You may should do some research what the `default` modifier really is.

Comment: You should really define what you mean by "valid" to get better answers. Because on a very basic level you can say if it compiles, it's valid. And you can check whether it compiles simply by compiling it.

Comment: If your program runs, then ofcourse it's valid, but that doesn't mean that it is needed/desirable or wotevr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a valid `abstract` class.

Abstract classes can have constructors, instance variables and concrete methods.

The main difference with regular classes is that they can *also* declare `abstract` methods, delegating implementation to the non-abstract child classes (this is not the case here, you have no `abstract` methods).

Another difference is that they cannot be initialized directly, even if they do provide an accessible constructor.

The constructor(s) of an abstract class are typically used to initialize values internally, and to invoke from child classes or anonymously.

See documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html).

**Example**

Given...

```
public abstract class Programmer {
    private String language;

    public Programmer(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public void writeCode() {
        System.out.println("Written in " + language);
    }
}
```

... and...

```
public class JavaProgrammer extends Programmer {
    public JavaProgrammer() {
        super("Java");
    }
}
```

**Concrete child class**

```
new JavaProgrammer().writeCode(); // prints "Java"
```

**Anonymous class** (note the empty class body `{}`)

```
new Programmer("JavaScript"){}.writeCode(); // prints "JavaScript"
```

Answer (score 0):

As you say, abstract classes cannot be instantiated. However, when a subclass of any abstract class is created, the first sentence in its constructor is a call to super(), which is nothing but a representation of the constructor of its parent class, the abstract class.

An abstract class can have instance variables and methods. It is even possible to have an abstract class without any abstract method. However, an abstract method can only be declared in an abstract class.

You are mixing abstract classes and interfaces concepts. An interface cannot have instance variables, and any implemented method must be prefixed with the static or default modifier.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct example of abstract class. Answering your questions:

- default keyword is used (as of java 8) in interfaces, where you can implement default method implementation, abstract class can have a method implementation just as any normal java class
- having constructor in abstract class imposes having a constructor in extending class so that the underlying abstract class can be properly constructed (e.g. fields instantiated etc)
- abstract class cannot be instantiated but as any other class can have private fields and internally make use of them, should they be protected then extending classes will also be able to directly access them.

It seems to me you're confusing abstract class with interface.

Answer (score 0):

The abstract class contains a constructor because when the instantiated class based on the abstract class is created it will call `super()` to execute the code from the abstract class.

The instance variable is a similar thing. The class that is developed from the abstract class would then have access to the `language` and be able to work with it.

In terms of the default, that would be best practice but there is no absolute requirement for it to be there.

Answer (score -1):

Abstract classes are partial implementations. Sometimes, as in the case above, the only thing that prevents the class from being instantiated is the `abstract` modifier itself!

If an abstract class has constructors then it means that subclasses must invoke one of the constructors (by calling `super(...)` in their constructor.

---

More broadly it seems that you're confusing Interfaces and Abstract Classes. Interfaces are a contract, they specify how a class should behave but provide no implementation whatsoever. Abstract Classes are a specific partial implementation of some code.

Interfaces are used (broadly) when you require someone else to provide behaviour but you don't care how it works. Abstract Classes are used when you want to assist people in providing behaviour, but you still require them to provide some details.

Since these definitions overlap, it's not unusual to see both Abstract Classes and Interfaces provided, e.g. the various Adapters in `java.swing.*`.

Comment: "An abstract class in java can be a perfectly instantiable class" is confusing or simply wrong since we can't instantiate abstract class. We can instantiate other classes which are no longer abstract, but extend abstract one explicitly or implicitly (like anonymous classes).